# How to find a new point on rectangle based on an known point on the same?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, transformation

[image]

I have rotated a rectangle a certain amount of degree and got the point(x,y)=(130,40) which was previously (152,60). Now i want to find the x,y(marked as red) value at another location based on the known value (130,40) of the rotated rectangle.

Comment: It does not look like we have enough information to deduce a specific point $(x,y)$ as indicated. Maybe you have a location on the original rectangle in mind.

Comment: I have the revised location of (521,60) on the rotated rectangle which is (130,40). Angle is also another info.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation has the form $$(x,y)\mapsto (a+x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha,b+y\cos\alpha+x\sin\alpha)$$
where $\alpha$ is your rotating angle and $a,b$ determine the translational part (and can be obtained from one point and image point if $\alpha$ is known).

Comment: can you please tell me the what values should a,b,x(r.h.s),y(r.h.s) based on the image values.?